# Generate grid of coordinate tuples

Tags: python, tuples, coordinates

Assume a `d`-dimensional integer grid, containing `n^d` (n >= 1) points.

I am trying to write a function that takes the number of domain points `n` and the number of dimensions `d` and returns a set that contains all the coordinate points in the grid, as tuples.

Example: intGrid (n=2, dim=2) should return the set:

```
{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}
```

**Note**: I cannot use `numpy` or any external imports.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a good set of built-in modules that provides most of the basic functionality you will probably need to start getting your things done.

One of such good modules is [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), where you will find all sorts of functions related to iterations and combinatorics. The perfect function for you is [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), that you can use as below:

```
from itertools import product

def grid(n, dim):
  return set(product(range(n), repeat=dim))

print(grid(2, 2))
# {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}

print(grid(2, 3))
# {(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)}
```